# Is there a way to @Autowire non overridden methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an interface that is implemented by multiple classes, and these classes also have some extra methods. If I autowire the class. Is there a way I can autowire these extra methods?

Example-

**Interface**

```
public interface ExampleInterface {
    String methodOne();
    String methodTwo();
}
```

**Service 1**

```
@Service
public class ServiceOne implements ExampleInterface {

    @Override
    String methodOne() {
        return "one";
    }
    
    @Override
    String methodTwo() {
        return "two";
    }

    String methodThree() {
        return "three";
    }
}
```

**Service 2**

```
@Service
public class ServiceTwo implements ExampleInterface {

    @Override
    String methodOne() {
        return "1";
    }
    
    @Override
    String methodTwo() {
        return "2";
    }

    String otherMethod() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

If I try to directly Autowire the service like this-

```
@Service
public class Service{

    ServiceOne serviceOne;

    @Autowired
    public Service(ServiceOne serviceOne) {
        this.serviceOne = serviceOne;
    }
}
```

then I am getting error something like this-

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in Service required a bean of type 'ServiceOne' that could not be found.
```

Comment: It seems that the package where ServiceOne is located is not scanned. Did you define/exclude packages for the ComponentScan? BTW: Beans are autowired, not methods.

Comment: @blafoo yes the package of ServiceOne is included in ComponentScan

Comment: Unable to reproduce when all classes are in the same package, so if the package has been correctly included the error is somewhere else. @blafoo In this case OP can use autowired on the method, because it is a constructor.

Comment: I was using @ConditionalOnProperty on the services, that is why it was not getting autowired. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using @ConditionalOnProperty on the services, that is why it was not getting autowired.